# imputing group mean for missing values in Pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby, missing-data

I have gone through similar questions asked here but they are not answering my question. Please do help if you find the time:

I have a dataframe with 2 variables  `'unit'(str), 'leaves_used'(float64)` and some other variables. I am trying to impute missing values for `'leaves_used'` for the `'unit'='Finance'`  with the group mean. I have written the following lines of code but the NaN is not being replaced. Can you please tell me what needs to change or if this is at all the correct procedure? Note: I am using the `Ipython.core.Interactiveshell` to avoid writing multiple `print()` commands

```
finance_mean=hr.groupby('unit').get_group('Finance')['leaves_used'].mean()
#This correctly computes the mean for the group
hr.loc[(hr['unit']=='Finance') & (hr['leaves_used'].isna()),:]
#This returns the sliced DataFrame for visual inspection which, in my case is one row
hr.loc[hr['unit']=='Finance', 'leaves_used'].replace(np.nan, finance_mean,inplace=True)
#This is running without error so I was assuming the mean replacement is being done
hr.loc[(hr['unit']=='Finance') & (hr['leaves_used'].isna()),:]
# This is to return the sliced dataframe again as before and I see that the NaN has not changed
```

Please help me correct this! Please also explain the reasoning behind why a different solution is required and this is not getting me the desired result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here , when we do the chain function we can not use `inplace`

```
hr.loc[(hr['unit']=='Finance') & (hr['leaves_used'].isna()),'leaves_used'] = finance_mean
```